# Nugetserver onpremise unable to run due to newtonsoft.json version

Tags: nuget-server

Target set as .net 4.6 in a vs2015 environment. All fetch and built no errors. 
Used https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx and MS doco as reference.
When run under IIS, shows error below

> > How do I resolve this ?

```
Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0
```

NB: Version on the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file is 9.0.1.19813
web.config has these 2 lines, do I need to make this and nugget.dll.config have newVersion="9.0.2.0" say ?

```
 < assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
 < bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, what I did was change the default project of "nuget" to "nugetwebserver" and adjusted the assemblies and module name. 
Then did a fresh compile. I suspect the poor choice of name caused some conflict with the some setting seeing by nuget.server project was called ..

Interestingly the http://server/nugetserver2.7/nuget would render in IE
http://server/nugetserver3.1/nuget asks me if I want to download the content.  The content being the same as the rendered page for 2.7..

Comment: default project of nuget? Could you elaborate? I have the same issue